# Any suggest to store a value in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, inline-code

I'm trying to write an in-line function for count occurrences of a word in a string using lambda expressions recursively.

The function:

```
Func<string, string, int> getOccurrences = null;
getOccurrences = (text, searchTerm) =>
  text.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1
  ? 0
  : getOccurrences(
      text.Substring(
        text.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        + searchTerm.Length),
      searchTerm) + 1;
```

The problem is that I'm call `IndexOf` method twice, 
The first one is for recursive break condition and the second one is to get the value for add it.

Is there any suggest to call it once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it work to just use a regex for this, maybe something like \b(search_term)\b. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this an exercise? Are you trying to do something else, and this is a non-representative sample? Do you want to use this in production code?

Comment: If you haven't yet, give ["Recursive lambda expressions"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx) a read.

Comment: Sorry, it's not an exercise*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind a non-pure-function lambda you can do:-

```
Func<string, string, int> getOccurrences = null;
getOccurrences = (text, searchTerm) => 
{
   int i = text.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
   return i == -1 ? 0 : getOccurrences(i + searchTerm.Length), searchTerm) + 1;
}
```

Comment: What is "non-pure" about that? (I am out of up-votes :-) It simply shows that a "non-lambda" (e.g. multiple lines in an anon-function/delegate) is a perfectly good (if not better) approach than a "pure lambda". I believe they are both compiled down the same, but have no verified this.

Comment: pst: It's "non-pure" in the sense that it's a lambda that you can't make into an `Expression<Func<string, string, int>>`

Comment: @Highttech: between the braces, is that like a delegate, then?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make it a separate method

```
   Func<string, string, int> getOccurrences = GetOccurrences;

   private int GetOccurrences(string text, string searchTerm)
   {
        //...    
   }
```

or inline

```
Func<string, string, int> getOccurrences = delegate(string text, string searchTerm)
                                           {
                                               //...
                                           };
```

with lambda syntax but just another way of writing the above

```
Func<string, string, int> getOccurrences = (string text, string searchTerm) =>
                                           {
                                               //...
                                           };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
Func<string, string, int> getOccurrences =
    (text, searchTerm) => getOccurrencesInternal(
        text,
        searchTerm,
        text.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
Func<string, string, int, int> getOccurrencesInternal = null;
getOccurrences = (text, searchTerm, index) => 
  index == -1 
  ? 0 
  : getOccurrencesInternal( 
      text.Substring( 
        index + searchTerm.Length), 
      searchTerm) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an additional, anonymous lambda and invoke it immediately. I'm not certain of the exact C# syntax, but it should look something like:

```
Func<string, string, int> getOccurrences = null;
getOccurrences = (text, searchTerm) =>
  ((index) =>
    index == -1
    ? 0
    : getOccurrences(text.Substring(index + searchTerm.Length),
        searchTerm) + 1
  )(text.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

My usual solution to these kind of problems, ignoring any optimizations, is just to remove the matching term and check any change in the resulting string's length.

```
Func<String, String, Int32> getOccurrences = (text, term) => 
    (text.Length - text.Replace(term, "").Length) / term.Length;
```